# Can a Script node using OSL have a checkbox?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I made a Cycles script node using OSL. Works great.  To modify what it does, is it possible to add a checkbox, like for example the "Clamp" checkbox in math nodes?

Answer (score 2):

There is a thing called 'string widget' (metadata syntax), which may be of some interest. The [OSL specs](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/doc/osl-languagespec.pdf) suggest it in page 18 chapter 4, but that syntax may not be implemented in cycles. I haven't seen any examples of its usage. (Except for [vray - 3dsmax docs](http://docs.chaosgroup.com/display/VRAY3/OSL+Support+in+V-Ray#))

if Implemented from the specs, it would look something like this:

```
int clamp = 0
    [[ string widget = "checkBox"]],
```

The implementor, Dingto, confirmed on IRC that metadata is not supported - yet.