# Will Blender update OSL specification from 1.5.1 to 1.6?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders, osl

Open shading language is a great feature for cycles render(Customizing parameters and algorithm so on. I try to put OSL to my lighting and shading pipeline. But OSL specification 1.5.1 leak some features like widget(For instances, Checkbox,Min-Max value etc.). It will be great if Blender can update OSL specification from 1.5.1 to 1.6. It can enhance the user(people who use my shader to work) experience. It is possible to update?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Blender development, and not about how to use Blender.

Comment: The OSL specs have 'suggested' metadata, which are not part of the osl core-specs and the implementation of which is really down to how programs implement their OSL node tree. See related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31380/can-a-script-node-using-osl-have-a-checkbox  I suspect at some point OSL will be updated

Comment: not a bad question btw, but this isn't really the venue for asking about blender future plans.. there are [mailinglists](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard) and irc (freenode) #blendercoders

Comment: The developer Thomas Dinges (Dingto, implementor of the OSL node) said this on 29Nov2015 "we will update OSL at some point, not sure yet when exactly though"